# Where is documentation for Actionlib Client?

Tags: actionlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [tutorial page for Actionlib Client](http://wiki.ros.org/roslibjs/Tutorials/ActionlibClient) has two references to further documentation, both of which have a broken link.

> "Documentation of all the constructor
> options and available functions can be
> found in the ROSLIB.ActionClient
> docs."
>
> "The ROSLIB.Goal docs describe all the
> constructor options and functions
> available. "

Can anyone tell me where this documentation is?  And, how do I raise this sort of issue?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221543/where-is-documentation-for-actionlib-client?/) by [Joseph Landau](https://answers.ros.org/users/5098/joseph-landau/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2015-11-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-11-25**:
That link refers specifically to the javascript (roslibjs) actionlib client. If you're not looking for the javascript version, you may want to start with the actionlib page: http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know where to find the source docs.

The path for that wiki page (near the top) provides a link to the package: http://wiki.ros.org/roslibjs ; the package page has links for the package's source code and their issue tracker. Given that this is a javascript package, you should probably have a look at their readme and report broken links on their issue tracker.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-11-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0